# How do I connect to an online database in Android?

Tags: android, database, connection

really having difficulty. New to Android development. How do I connect to an online database? Php, Java or? Php not working, dunno what to do with the php file, it wont work. How do i put in on the server side if i have to on myphpadmin? Is java a better way? I want to do a login screen and also populate listviews, add multiple data etc. to the database. Can't figure out how to reference the actual database on myphpadmin server, must i use the database password and username of the databe or reference the database html?

Also how do i check if i do connect to the database?

Please I'd appreciate any help at all.

Comment: to access a database from outside the device try using an API to retrieve data and to put data to your database and NOT accessing directly since its not a good practice and also unsafe.

Comment: I would suggest you build a service to your database, and access your data that way.

Comment: please check this : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/connecting-mysql-database-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Lookup tutorials on RESTful Web Service, you can implement this on Java Servlet, PHP, or ASP.NET. The idea is that the Web Service layer serves as the middleman between your app, and the database. Or, if you prefer, add another layer of application server logic between the Web Service and the database.

Once you have the Web Service implemented correctly, you can expose CRUD methods to your app as you see fit. e.g. PUT request to create a database entry, GET to retrieve it, POST to update it, and DELETE to delete it.

Of course, you need to add some kind of authentication logic, to limit or allow certain Web Services method to certain authorized users.